# Oracle SQL- column value being not distinct as criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, dml

I'm having trouble formulating a SQL statement to return the values I want. I need to select data based on user ID, a second column's value, and a third columns value where the values in that column appear more than once. All columns are within the same table.

Here's a rough outline of what my query looks like now, but the last AND statement obviously is just to give you an idea of what I want. A COUNT statement that would narrow the results down likely wouldn't work for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 123
AND second_id = 1
AND third_id having COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is the columns user_id, second_id, third_id then try this:

```
SELECT user_id, second_id, third_id, COUNT(1) 
FROM table
WHERE user_id = 123
AND second_id = 1
GROUP BY  user_id, second_id, third_id
HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1;
```

If you have additional columns and want to get those fields as well try this(Oracle 9.2 & above):

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.*,
            COUNT(1)  OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, second_id, third_id) rpt_count
FROM table a
WHERE user_id = 123
AND second_id = 1
)
SELECT *
  FROM qry 
    WHERE rpt_count > 1
```

Comment: The 2nd option looks like what I needed, thank you. However, I think there's still one more step that I will need if you could assist- I need to use these results as part of a sub-query, so the full query will look at those results and return the MIN(fourth_id) from the results.